# how to get textbox to show results

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

trying to get results in textbox18, but no results. Is there something wrong with this code?

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim id As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

id = Me.ComboBox17.Text
finalrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B27").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 7 To finalrow
    If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Text = id Then
        Me.TextBox18 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 9).Text

        End If

    Next i


End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Suggest to fully qualify your range references to be sure to address the correct workbook, e.g. via `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").`…  Assuming there exists another `Sheet2` currently active, your lastrow Formula would result in row 1 if its column B is empty and your loop wouldn't show anything. BTW I'd prefer `Worksheets` to `Sheets` only as these comprise not only worksheets, but also shapes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the textbox itself is an object, in which the `Text` is a field. So if you want to change that field's value, you should try:

```
Me.TextBox18.Text = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 9).Text
```

Comment: That's odd. The problem isn't the assignment, then. I would check if the other values are correct. See if the "id" is actually in ComboBox17, if "finalrow" is what you're expecting it to be, as well as if there's something in `Cells(i, 9)`. Here's a sample that runs pretty much your snippet: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiOspEx0IwKt8k5bfyYefbIO_uTF

Comment: i have added two screen shots. in the form the flange size is combobox17, the results should show in textbox18 "torque value".    if combobox17 = "4" then textbox18 should be "89"

Comment: or i could figure out how to use lookup formula in vba  using combobox17 text ..?*